# Password reset updated but still able to login with old password in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, login

I have reset my password.

It shows as Password updated. But still i can able to login with old password. Newly updated password is not working.

My magento version is 2.2.6.

**Note:** I am using Store session In DB instead of files.

Can anyone look into this issue please.

Comment: able to login with new and old both the password?
getting any error or exception in log?

Comment: Only able to login with old password. new password not updated

Answer (score 1):

Look's like default Magento bug.

Check the GIT url : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18256

A temporary fix is to modify the `vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\AccountManagement.php`.
Go to function `resetPassword()` and
Replace following lines (around line # 673):

```
$this->sessionManager->destroy();
$this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
```

with following lines

```
  try {
            $this->sessionManager->destroy();
            $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
     } catch (\Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: Reference link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7443dc3194040e9ce2f7baf902470deb975b97c6

Comment: I am storing session id Db

Comment: hi @Amit, Tried this but its not working again.

Comment: hi, @Rohanhapani, can you check this issue please

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex and then check.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It should work then !!!

Comment: hi @Yash shaw, Yes tried it, but not updated..

Comment: Was your indexing done successfully or you see any issues in cli ? i mean if something breaks the process, some custom extension ?

Comment: reindex done successfully